# Importance of Ornstein's isomorphism theorem

Tags: pr.probability, ergodic-theory, intuition, statistical-physics

"Perhaps the most important parts of the Ornstein theory are criteria for determining whether or not a shift or flow is Bernoulli (a Bernoulli shift, $B_{ct}$ , or $B_{t}^{\infty}$) because it allows us to prove that certain concrete systems are Bernoulli."[Quote from scholarpedia][1]  [1]: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Ornstein_theory

Firstly, can you mention some profound applications and a bit of the intuition of the power of this theorem?

So say I have a dynamical system with action T isomorphic (by $\phi$) to a Bernouli system with action S, then $S(x)=\phi(T)(x)$. Any interesting examples with explicit $\phi$?

Can you mention some interesting applications of this theorem especially in the field of Probability intersecting with Statistical mechanics models like SLE and Spin glasses?

Thanks

Comment: You should probably read some of the earlier papers (Adler-Weiss,Ornstein-Weiss), where they've constructed the Markov partitions for Toral automorphisms and geodesic flows respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to start with this article by Ornstein:

An Application of Ergodic Theory to Probability Theory, Donald S. Ornstein, 
The Annals of Probability, Vol. 1, No. 1 (Feb., 1973), pp. 43-58